# Trying to create a k8s service account and bind it to a GCP service account through Workload Identity. No errors, but also no binding

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kustomize, workload-identity

I have followed the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#config-connector_1) and set up Config Connector. When I run `kubectl apply` I get no errors, just this warning

```
Warning: resource configconnectors/configconnector.core.cnrm.cloud.google.com is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
```

But then when I run `gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy [service account]` I don't see the binding, and my application does not have the permissions it needs. However, if I run everything again, I get an "unchanged" message, so it seems like it is being created, but the wrong place (if that is even possible). If I manually add the binding with the gcloud command, everything works great. Here are my relevant k8s files.

iam-policy.yml:

```
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMPolicy
metadata:
  name: iampolicy-workload-identity
spec:
  resourceRef:
    apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    kind: IAMServiceAccount
    name: review-instance-account@*********.gserviceaccount.com
  bindings:
    - role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
      members:
        - serviceAccount:*********.svc.id.goog[review-9/sand-access]
```

service-account.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: review-instance-account@********.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  name: sand-access
  namespace: review-apps
```

configconnector.yml:

```
apiVersion: core.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: ConfigConnector
metadata:
  # the name is restricted to ensure that there is only one
  # ConfigConnector resource installed in your cluster
  name: configconnector.core.cnrm.cloud.google.com
spec:
  mode: cluster
  googleServiceAccount: 'review-instance-account********.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/):

**Possibly the error occurred due to the missing configuration file.**

> The kubectl apply command writes the contents of the configuration
> file to the `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation` This is used to identify fields that have been removed
> from the configuration file and need to be cleared from the live
> configuration. Here are the steps used to calculate which fields
> should be deleted or set:
>
> Calculate the fields to delete. These are the fields present in
> last-applied-configuration and missing from the configuration file.
>
> Calculate the fields to add or set. These are the fields present in
> the configuration file whose values don't match the live
> configuration.

It simply informs you that the resource was likely created by someone else because the annotation is missing. In order to prevent you from receiving the warning in the future, it is alerting you to the possibility that a different entity is managing that resource and promising to add the missing annotation.

The below information is derived from the official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/advanced-install) :

> **There are two  advanced installation  options for installing Config Connector on your Google Kubernetes Engine cluster**:
>
> **Manual installation**: Installing with the manual method provides you with faster updates than using the add-on. This method also
> provides you with more configuration options. For example, you can
> increase the CPU limit of the Config Connector Operator. Before you
> manually install Config Connector Operator, complete the following
> steps:Create or identify a GKE cluster where Config Connector has not
> yet been installed and that has Workload Identity and Kubernetes
> Engine Monitoring enabled.
>
> **Namespaced mode**: This method is an extension of the Config Connector installation. Namespaced mode supports managing multiple
> projects, each with their own Google Cloud identities.
>
> Before configuring Config Connector to run in namespaced mode, ensure
> that you have enabled the [Config Connector GKE add-on](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall) or manually
> installed Config Connector Operator.

For choosing an installation follow the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/concepts/installation-types)